# Recuperar uma branch no Git

Tags: git

Eu fiz um checkout para um commit antigo de uma aplicação e apareceu a seguinte mensagem:

> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make
> experimental changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits
> you make in this state without impacting any branches by switching
> back to a branch.
>
> If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you
> may do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:
>
> git switch -c
>
> Or undo this operation with:
>
> git switch -
>
> Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to
> false
>
> HEAD is now at 4bf36b5 Created component transactions

Nesse commit existem dois branches, o Master e um outro que eu criei algumas funcionalidades novas. Quando entro nessa branch com as mudanças estão todas lá, mas ainda não estão na Master.

Quando dou um git status aparece pra mim essa mensagem:

> HEAD detached at 4bf36b5 nothing to commit, working tree clean

Não tem nada pra commitar em nenhuma branch e quando tento fazer o merge da feature para master aparece isso:

> $ git merge featureTransactions Already up to date.

Alguém pode me dar uma dica do que está ocorrendo? Estou precisando subir essas mudanças e dar um push dela no github substituindo o que está lá, pois quebrou minha aplicação algumas mudanças que eu fiz.

Comment: Experimente, antes de tentar fazer o merge, dar checkout na master: ```git checkout master``` e depois ```git merge branchDaFeature```. O que acontece?

Comment: $ git merge featureTransactions
Already up to date.

Comment: Isso quer dizer que todas as modificações da ```featureTransactions``` já estão contidas na ```master```. O que te leva a crer que não?

Comment: Só que as mudanças estão na outra branch mas na master não.

Answer (score 1):

Quando aparecer a mensagem `HEAD detached at 4bf36b5 nothing to commit, working tree clean`  você está livre pra criar um novo branch, no ponto em que está - basta dar o comando `git branch <nome_da_nova_branch>` , e pode subir esse novo branch parao repositório com `git push -u origin <nome...>` - pronto, ai você já se garantiuu contra perdas.

Aí se a ideia é juntar na master o que está aí,  é, estando nesse branch `git merge master` - vai atualizar seu feature branch com o que foi desenvolvido na master . Opcionalmente você poderia fazer "rebase" em vez de merge - mas se mexeu em arquivos que foram mexidos na master, vai ter conflitos que podem ser chatos de resolver. Acho que não teria muita vantagem nesse caso.

BOm, feito o merge com a master, teste o seu branch, se está funcionando ok, e com as features que você queria incluir, é só mudar para o master, e fazer novamente `git merge <nome...>` (esse passo pod ser feito pela interface web do github/gitlab/etc... via pull request, se preferir)